# CQL3 trigger implementation

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am trying to implement a trigger for C*. The need for the trigger in this specific case is really out of scope of this question, I think I could use it in order to provide the materialized view to support one infrequent use case for my data.

The table that I am watching with the trigger has composite row and column keys. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    uid     uuid,
    d_id    blob,
    a_id    uuid,
    cname   ascii,
    cl_id   blob,
    e_id    blob,
    <some more fields>
PRIMARY KEY ((uid, d_id, a_id, cname), cl_id, e_id)
...
```

So, in my trigger code I need to decompose the row key and column key for the data. And, in addition to that, I would like to write some values into another (CQL) table with my trigger - which means generating the appropriate composite row key. And column name from clustering key values.

What is the most appropriate and safest way to do that? I am trying to use CompositeType to decompose the original row key. Which method should I use for the column name? Maybe someone could point me to more comprehensive example of the code that writes into CQL3 table using low-level Cassandra API? I think this is not the right way of dealing with the problem but triggers can only deal with low-level API.

Comment: I think I managed to get my trigger working and what it produces can be queried with CQL. I had to look at UpdateStatement and ModificationStatement implementation to get some ideas but it was more or less clear. I wish CQL3/Cassandra developers could make the API for generating the list of mutations for a statement more clear (or it is available and I am missing something?). Something that would allow to create a prepared statement in the trigger and then just supply the parameters and get the list of mutations :)

Comment: I also think that calling `CompositeType.extractComponent` is not efficient if I need to extract like 2-3 or more components - it parses the entire key every time. Is there more elegant method (without copying the code from CompositeType) to get all composite type components in one pass?

Answer (score 0):

Working code to decompose composite keys is here. 
https://github.com/tuplejump/stargate-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tuplejump/stargate/cassandra/WideRowIndexSupport.java

Please ask if you need further clarifications.